# MVC Binding complex objects with list of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have looked at most of the available help in SO and google related to this but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have Model with some properties, and one of the properties is a list of another complex object. I'm not able to bind this list!

Pleas help!

**Here is my Model classes related:**

```
public class PrivacyModel
{
        public int RatingId { get; set; }
        public List<RatingPoint> RatingPoints { get; set; }
}

public class RatingPoint
{
        public int RatingItemId { get; set; }
        public string RatingValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my code:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(PrivacyModel model)
 {
     .... my business logic....
 }
```

**My view looks like this:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Privacy"))
        {

            <input type="hidden" name="RatingId" value="@Model.RatingId" />

            for (var i = 0; i < Model.RatingPoints.Count; i++)
            {

                var ratingPoint = Model.RatingPoints[i];

                <input type="hidden" name="PrivacyModel.RatingPoints[@i].RatingItemId" value="@ratingPoint.RatingItemId" />

                <input type="hidden" name="PrivacyModel.RatingPoints[@i].RatingValue" @("id=RatingPoints" + ratingPoint.RatingItemId) value="@ratingPoint.RatingValue" />
            }
       <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
     }
```

Please don't mind the value and id fields, they are being updated by *jQuery* somewhere in my page correctly.

This got me a null list of `RatingPoints` in my action

I have tried also without the prefix `PrivacyModel` in `PrivacyModel.RatingPoints[@i].`, but this got me an empty list of `RatingPoints` in my action

I have also tried using an Index like in the suggested solution [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/#non-sequential-indices) for non-sequential items

Comment: Always use the strongly typed HtmlHelper methods to generate your html. - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RatingPoints[i].RatingItemId)` - now inspect the correct name attribute it generates with yours :)

Comment: I will try, as also suggested by [Ehsans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623290/mvc-binding-complex-objects-with-list-of-values/#answer-36623484) answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it complex yourself, you can just use `HiddenFor()` helper for this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.RatingPoints.Count; i++)
{


  @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.RatingPoints[i].RatingItemId)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.RatingPoints[i].RatingValue,new { id= "RatingPoints"+Model.RatingPoints[i].RatingItemId})      

 }
```

and this will render the same html, and values will be correctly binded in Model at post.